# How can I calculate my car's speed from a dash cam video?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, physics, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-physics

I have a dash camera on my windshield, and I'm wondering if there is any way to determine my vehicle's speed using the video footage from the dash cam.  Please help!

Comment: Yes, it's called [visual odometry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_odometry) and it is a computer vision question, not really one for this forum. I would suggest to look for opencv tutorials on the subject, and possibly asking at http://answers.opencv.org/questions/

Comment: Speed is distance over time. You would need to find a known distance between 2 objects, and then find the time it took to travel this distance.

Comment: As @rschwieb mentions it's a whole subfield of machine vision. Probably more papers have been written about methods to do that than anyone here can answer. If you have some mathematical maturity the easier approach would be to start searching for such papers describing how to do.

Answer (score 3):

The federal guideline for the white dashed lines on roads is 10 feet, and the empty spaces in between are 30 feet. If you measure the time it takes to move from the beginning of one white dashed line to the next, that is the time it takes your car to move 40 feet, which is a measure of speed.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy may be to use the dashed lines in the lane dividers.

A source like [this](http://commons.bcit.ca/civil/edufacts/highway_paint.html) can provide size and spacing. Then mean velocity $v$ can be expressed in terms of, $d$, distance (on the video) and time, $t$, (a watch your arm):
$$
 \bar{v} = \frac{d}{t}
$$

Comment: Thanks!  Assuming that the white lines are spaced at a standardized interval, how could I use that to go about calculating speed from video?